# Little and Big Endian

Tags: endianness

Suppose the number Ox12345678 is stored at memory location 1000 in Big 
Endian format. If the processor now assumes the data to be in Little Endian 
format, what will it get if it reads (i) a byte, (ii) a half-word, (iii) a word from 
the location 1000?

This is in relation to the ARM processor

Answer (score 0):

If the number Ox12345678 in your question is given in *Little Endian* format and you store it in *Big Endian* format at address 1000, then the memory image at that address will be:

- 1000 - 0x78
- 1001 - 0x56
- 1002 - 0x34
- 1003 - 0x12

Now, using a *Little-Endian* processor:

- If you read a byte from address 1000 then you'll get 0x78.
- If you read a half-word from address 1000 then you'll get 0x7856.
- If you read a word from address 1000 then you'll get 0x78563412.

---

If the number Ox12345678 in your question is given in *Big Endian* format and you store it in *Big Endian* format at address 1000, then the memory image at that address will be:

- 1000 - 0x12
- 1001 - 0x34
- 1002 - 0x56
- 1003 - 0x78

Now, using a *Little-Endian* processor:

- If you read a byte from address 1000 then you'll get 0x12.
- If you read a half-word from address 1000 then you'll get 0x1234.
- If you read a word from address 1000 then you'll get 0x12345678.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My question assumes the number is given in the Little Endian format. Just one question: In the first part of the answer, you specified that 1000 has 0x87 data. Shouldn't it be 0x78?

Comment: Just another quick question. If the data bus lines are connected to the memory in reverse order (bit 0 to bit 31), will the readings be 84,842C,842C6A1E?